# How many Azure VM Instances in Free trial

Tags: azure, virtual

As I know we can try Azure for one month.

I need to know how many Windows VMs we can run for a month?

Thanks,
NRatawa

Answer (score 2):

According to the Azure website:

> You receive a €170 credit to spend on Azure services during the trial. You can use this €170 however you want to create and try out any combination of Azure resources. It enables you to explore our cloud entirely for free.

So the actual ammount of VM's you can use will depend on the price and the size of the VM's: [See here](http://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/pricing/details/virtual-machines/)